# SQL Query not returning desired result - Movie Database query

Tags: sql, database

I have this table:

```
actors(id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string, gender: string)
directors(id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string)
directors genres(director id: int, genre: string, prob: float)
movies(id: int, name: string, years: int, rank: float)
movies directors(director id: int, movie id: int)
movies genres(movie id: int, genre: string)
roles(actor id: int, movie id: int, role: string)
```

I want to find the list of actors who have acted in all the comedy movies directed by Wilson Yip in the year 2002.

I am doing the following:

```
select distinct A.first_name, 
       A.last_name, 
       M.name
  from actors A inner join roles R 
                      on A.id=R.actor_id
                inner join movies M 
                      on M.id=R.movie_id
  where M.name in ( select M.name
                      from movies M inner join movies_genres G 
                                       on M.id = G.movie_id
                                    inner join movies_directors MD 
                                       on M.id = MD.movie_id
                                    inner join directors D 
                                       on D.id = MD.director_id
                     where G.genre = 'Comedy' 
                       and M.year = 2002 
                       and D.first_name='Wilson' 
                       and D.last_name='Yip');
```

But, this gives me list of actors who have acted in a comedy movie directed by Wilson in 2002, but I want actors who have acted in 'all' such comedies.

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean you want all actors who have acted in 'all' such comedies.

Comment: "I want to find the list of actors who have acted in all the comedy movies directed by Wilson Yip in the year 2002."  and "But, this gives me list of actors who have acted in a comedy movie directed by Wilson in 2002, but I want actors who have acted in 'all' such comedies." seems to say to me that you got the answer you wanted, no?

Comment: @evanv No, for example, there are 2 such comedy movies that Wilson Yip directed in 2002. I want the actors that acted in both those movies, and not in either of them. This gives me either, right?

Comment: Use a subquery to check

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's find out what is the number of:
Commedies, directed by Wilson Yip in 2002 year.We are doing that , in order  to establish which actors acted in all of them(later on):

```
declare @totalNumberOfMovies as int =(
Select count(*) 
from 
movies m
inner join 
movies_genres  mg
on m.movie_id=mg.movied_id
inner join movies_directors md
on mg.movie_id=md.movie_id
inner join directors d
on md.director_id=d.director_id
where mg.genre='Comedy' and  d.first_name='Wilson' and d.last_name='Yip' and m.year='2002'
);
```

the total number of commedies, directed by Wilson Yip in 2002 year has been assigned to the variable.

Now, You have to join all tables You need(include all filters), group by actor's name and surname and include the "Having Count(*)" filter that has to have the value equal to the previously defined variable @totalNumberOfMovies.

It will give You only actors that acted in ALL movies.Instead of using variable, You could use a subquery.

Regards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of such movies using a subquery, and put that into the `having` clause, like:

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, m.name
  from (select r.actor_id
          from movies M
          join movies_genres G
            on M.id = G.movie_id
          join movies_directors MD
            on M.id = MD.movie_id
          join directors D
            on D.id = MD.director_id
          join roles r
            on r.movie_id = m.id
         group by r.actor_id
        having count(*) = (select count(*) as num_of_movies
                            from movies M
                            join movies_genres G
                              on M.id = G.movie_id
                            join movies_directors MD
                              on M.id = MD.movie_id
                            join directors D
                              on D.id = MD.director_id
                           where G.genre = 'Comedy'
                             and M.year = 2002
                             and D.first_name = 'Wilson'
                             and D.last_name = 'Yip')) x
  join actors a
    on a.id = x.actor_id
  join roles r
    on a.id = r.actor_id
  join movies m
    on m.id = r.movie_id
```

Alternatively you can put that subquery into the `from` clause as an `inline view` and and join it to another inline view where the count per actor is computed, and then join back to the original tables for the fields you want, like:

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, m.name
  from (select r.actor_id, count(*) as movies_this_actor
          from movies M
          join movies_genres G
            on M.id = G.movie_id
          join movies_directors MD
            on M.id = MD.movie_id
          join directors D
            on D.id = MD.director_id
          join roles r
            on r.movie_id = m.id
         group by r.actor_id) x
  join (select count(*) as movies_total
          from movies M
          join movies_genres G
            on M.id = G.movie_id
          join movies_directors MD
            on M.id = MD.movie_id
          join directors D
            on D.id = MD.director_id
         where G.genre = 'Comedy'
           and M.year = 2002
           and D.first_name = 'Wilson'
           and D.last_name = 'Yip') y
    on x.movies_this_actor = y.movies_total
  join actors a
    on a.id = x.actor_id
  join roles r
    on a.id = r.actor_id
  join movies m
    on m.id = r.movie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL can be optimised, but roughly, you could try something like the following, if you are using Oracle.

```
with wilson_yip_2002_comedies as
  (
    select m.id
    from movies m, movies_genres mg, movies_directors md, directors d
    where m.id = mg.movie_id
    and m.id = md.movie_id
    and md.director_id = d.id
    and mg.genre = 'Comedy'
    and m.years = 2002
    and d.first_name = 'Wilson'
    and d.last_name = 'Yip'
)
select a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, count(r.movie_id) n_movies
from actors a, roles r, wilson_yip_2002_comedies
where a.id = r.actor_id
and r.movie_id = wilson_yip_2002_comedies.id
group by a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name
having count(r.movie_id) = (
  select count(1) 
  from wilson_yip_2002_comedies);
```

Steps:

- Basically you can get all the comedies that Wilson Yip directed in
  2002, and then cross it with the actors via the roles. That would
  give you any actor that had a role in at least one of the movies.
- But because you want actors with a part in ALL the movies, you can
  group by the movie_id and add a HAVING condition to filter the
  results in order to select those with a part in as many comedy movies
  as Wilson Yip directed in 2002.
- And because you do not have the number of comedies in advance, you
  need a query to get it as well.

If you cannot use WITH, you could write the whole query twice, although that is not very neat.

Please try to provide an easy way to reproduce your problem when possible, like this SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b05c/5

Hope this helps.